# Wallet mobile app that allows sending transactions with data to smart contracts on BSC?

Tags: transactions, bsc, mobile-wallet, data

I have tried about a dozen crypto wallet apps on Android, including Metamask, and I haven't found a single one that:

- supports BSC (BNB Smart Chain)
- allows me to manually initiate and send a transaction to a smart contract with data. That is, basically, to interact with a smart contract at all.

**EDIT:** let me clarify, I mean an app that allows me to do that **manually** without the need for whoever wrote the contract to have also developed a website frontend that initiates the transaction for me. What I'm looking for is the ability to: go to Send, enter the recipient address (a contract's address), enter the hex data and hit Confirm/Send/Whatever. Just like you do on the Metamask browser extension.

Does anybody know one?

Actually I haven't even found one that satisfies the second requirement alone, even on the Ethereum network.

Metamask is the only one that does have the option, but it doesn't work. You need to go to Advanced Settings and enable an option to "Show hex data field in transactions", and then it does show a "hex data" field when you make a transaction, but it doesn't allow you to enter anything in it, so I don't know what's the point of that.

I'm shocked that I have spent one afternoon trying all the wallet apps that I could find in Google Play and none of them has the most basic feature that is expected of a wallet.

On desktop, the very first that I tried was the Metamask browser extension for Chrome and  and it works.

Oh! It would be a plus if it also supported EIP-681 links. That is, you click on such a link from your default browser (e.g. Chrome) and it opens the wallet app and does the transaction. Again, MetaMask behaves as if it had this feature, but it's broken. It will actually send a transaction to the target address with the set amount, but with no data (and with no warning!), causing the transaction to fail and be reverted (which costs you the gas fees).

Comment: It's 2024 and I can't make this work either; i.e., I'm trying to use an EIP-681 URI but MetaMask does not support it (i.e., no way to use the URI in the desktop browser extension, and, while the link (or QR code) does open the MetaMask app on mobile, it does not prepare the transaction described by EIP-681.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mobile wallets allow interaction with smart contracts using [WalletConnect protocol](https://docs.walletconnect.com/), so they probably assume there's no need to manually create a transaction with arbitrary data.

MetaMask used to be the exception, but the feature has been broken for years due to a trivial UI bug, and the assumption above may be the reason why they don't deem it a priority to fix it.

So no, there's currently no mobile wallet app allowing to do that.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that requires the existence of some web front-end. What I mean by being able to send a transaction to a contract from a wallet is: go to Send, enter the amount and the data, and send, without requiring any additional software or website besides the wallet. All the apps I tried lack a data field, which is essential for contract interactions.

Comment: All DApps have frontend. There is no point to type in data fields on mobile phones, or any wallets. If there is no frontend, one can create such with little HTML/JavaScript skills in a few days. Or you directly interact with contracts using BSCScan and mobile wallet. Your question feels like https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Ok, so the answer is: there exists none (except for metamask which has it but is broken), because the prevailing narrow-minded approach is that "you don't need that". Dapps *usually* provide a front-end that prepares the transaction for you so then the wallet will allow you to execute it. BSCScan does the same thing. But if you want to create the transaction manually from scratch, they don't allow you to do that. Most desktop wallets do, but not mobile ones, because why would you need to do something from a mobile phone that is perfectly reasonable to do from a desktop computer.

Comment: Regarding the statement that "all DApps have frontends": I'm not sure what exactly qualifies as a DApp by definition; but either that isn't true, or using a dapp is not the only use case for interacting with a smart contract.

Comment: There are over 30M non-custodial smart contract mobile wallet users and they do not have this problem. Thus, somehow the problem is specific to you and no one else has encountered it before, so it is likely that you are doing something very niche or doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes they do have this problem, in that they can't manually make an arbitrary transaction to a smart contract with data without depending on a web3 front-end preparing the transaction for them, but apparently most of them are happy with that, as they prefer to click on a button anyway, and apparently many dapp developers are happy developing the front-ends as they provide a better UX anyway, so yes they do have this very problem it's just not an issue to them. And I never said it is not niche I just asked if there was an app that allows to do that.

Comment: "no there isn't" (such an app) is a perfectly good answer. "You are doing it wrong" is just not correct in this case. That what I'm doing is something very niche depends on where one puts the threshold for "niche"; either way, a design that only addresses known mainstream use cases, instead of allowing the widest (easily) conceivable range of possibilities (allowing for "niche" use cases that haven't even been thought of yet - and note that's far from being my case) is flawed.